# What would be better set, array or list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, set

I need to make a list of people and their time of arrival to a party, and when ever they leave I need to take them off this list. (the party maximum is 150)

Set would provide me that in no case I would add the same person twice.

List would provide me flexibility to start the list with few spaces (in case no one shows up).

Arrays (not sure what they provide) but I used them more often.

My idea was either to create 2 arrays one with names and what with times. When someone comes in, I save name in one and time on the other. When he/she leaves I search for his/her name, delete it and use the same index to delete the time on the other array.

A list could have one array of 2 elements, and then I will only need to add it in one location but searching would be a TINY more complicated.

Or maybe I am complicating this too much?

Comment: How about a map keyed by person, with time as the value?

Comment: you don't need 2 arrays; you can have an array of object Person { time, name } too

Comment: what operations are you trying to do on the data? what does the input look like?

Comment: I suspect that since you are dealing with 150 records, adding complexity into the setup wouldn't give you much gain.  If we were talking thousands, maybe.  What about a sorted list?  Searching that would be very fast, even though again, a lot of effort for 150 records.

Comment: Nop this was not a homework and in reality is not about people going to a party, but I think it was a little easier to explain this way. Looking back I think the question may have been a little stupid, but still got really nice answers to think about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map implementation:

```
public final class Person
{
  ... remainder left to the student ...
}

Map<Person, Date> currentPartyAttendees; // date is arrival time.
```

Set implementation:

```
public final class PartyAttendee
{
  ... person details ...
  Date arrive;

  int hashcode()
  {
    ... use Apache HashCodeBuilder ... 
  }

  boolean equals(Object other)
  {
    ... implementation left to student.  Use Apache EqualsBuilder ...
  }
}

Set<PartyAttendee> currentPartyAttendees;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a HasMap would suit your purpose, as you can use the person's name as a key to add and retrieve the entry for the person, and it offers constant time performance, so regardless of how large the set grows, the performance should remain consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've described your use-case, why not consider the [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), or some other [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) based implementation?

Unless of course, there's a binding for you to use a `List` [or similar] based data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a List<> and a Data structure the represents guest.
Subclass List to mark the arrival and departure time and add/remove methods. You can also use set, but then you'll have to generate a hashCode and equals method. I'm not sure you want to do that, cause people may have the same names (unless you have other data like SSN, bday, middle name etc)

```
public Class Guest{
   private String firstName, lastName;
   private long arrivalTime, departureTime;
   ....
}

public class MyGuests extends ArrayList<Guest>{
     @Overide
     public void add(Guest g){
     //record arrival time here
          super.add(g)
     }
     @Overide
     public void remove(Guest g){
     //record departure time here
          super.remove(g);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use arrays as well, and, instead two arrays, use an arrays of 'Person' model, that holds the name of the person, arrive time and leave time. Before you insert on array, you can verify if the list already contains this person.

ps: don't forget to overwrite equals() and hashCode() in your model

Answer (score 0):

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) - a container of key-value pairs that maintains the order of their insertion. The key would be the person (a simple `String` or a designated class), the value would be the time of arrival, e.g. a `Date`.